# How can I have 2 files with the same name in my swift project?

Tags: swift

In my swift project, I have 2 files in different directory with the same name.
When I compile using 'swift build', I get error saying

```
 filename "File.swift" used twice: '/Users/myself/directory1/File.swift' and '/Users/myself/anotherdirectory/File.swift'<unknown>:0: note: filenames are used to distinguish private declarations with the same name<unknown
```

And in each of the file, they are having their different 'namespace' using
File.swift in directory1

```
extension directory1 {
   class A {
   }
}
```

File.swift in anotherdirectory

```
extension anotherdirectory {
   class A {
   }
}
```

Is there a way to work around this compile error without renaming the files?

Basically, I have 2 classes with the same name and they are in 2 files with same file name but in different directory. Can I get the code to compile? I tried wrapping the classes in different namespace (via different exteions, but that does not resolve the compile error.

Is there another solution without renaming the filename and class name?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot name the files the same. The solution is to include namespaces in filenames, instead of relying on folder structure.

So in your case, the file names would be:

`directory1.A` and `anotherdirectory.A`.